# I have to reload dataset to display crosstable in Jupyter Notebook Python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I can not display crosstable in Jupyter Notebook using Python 3. So as to do it I have to firstly load dataset again, and then when I create next crosstab I have to again load dataset. What is wrong ? My code is correct, because crosstabs work, but I as said, after reload of dataset. My code of example crosstab is:

```
#Percentage Crosstable of Housing and Purpose 
crossHousingPurpose = pd.crosstab(data["Housing"], data["Purpose"]).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum() * 100)
crossHousingPurposeRounded = round(crossHousingPurpose , 2)
crossHousingPurposeRounded
```

and when I start it using below code it works:

```
with open("german_credit_data.csv") as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0)

#Percentage Crosstable of Housing and Purpose 
crossHousingPurpose = pd.crosstab(data["Housing"], data["Purpose"]).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum() * 100)
crossHousingPurposeRounded = round(crossHousingPurpose, 2)
crossHousingPurposeRounded
```

What is wrong ? Please help me

Comment: One unrelated thing to note: When using `pd.read_csv()`, it's not necessary to use the `with open...` context manager, that's all handled by pandas automatically

Comment: Ok but it probably does not solve my problem ? ;)

Comment: True, hence the "unrelated" part :) . Regarding the actual question, what operations are you performing between when you create the crosstab and when you try to use `crossHousingPurposeRounded` again?

Comment: I create other crosstables and each crosstable I have to display using before code which load dataset

Comment: Do your other variables persist? For example, if you set `my_var= 42` then call it again later, are you able to do so?

Comment: Also, are there any warnings or errors regarding the kernel at the top of your notebook?

Comment: yes I can call it again late, and I do not have any mistakes at the top of the notebook, do you have other suggestion ? ;/

Comment: Just to help understand your issue. You create `data` with `read_csv()` successfully. You then assign `crossHousingPurpose = pd.crosstab(data["Housing"], data["Purpose"]).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum() * 100)`. Then, in the next cell, you call, for example, `crossHousingPurpose.shape`: what is the result? Is there an error?